# Change remoteServiceBaseUrl when building for production

Tags: angular, angular-cli, assets, environment, aspnetboilerplate

When wanting to deploy to a server, we need to change `remoteServiceBaseUrl` in **/src/assets/appconfig.json**.

Is there a way to set `remoteServiceBaseUrl`/`appBaseUrl` differently depending on the environment?

Comment: You could use a tool like Gulp for that.

Comment: I'm using the angular cli, So I was hoping there was a more "standardized" way to do this. It seems appconfig.json is something created by ASP ABP - not a normal angular thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I rewrote AppPreBootstrap.ts with the following changes:

Added
`import { environment } from 'environments/environment';`

Changed `getApplicationConfig()` to:

```
var version = environment.name ? '.' + environment.name : '';
return abp.ajax({
    url: '/assets/appconfig' + version + '.json',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Abp.TenantId': abp.multiTenancy.getTenantIdCookie()
    }
```

And inside the environment config, I have a "name" parameter which matches the environment.name.json filename.

Now I can have appconfig.production.json and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use environment-specific files, e.g. **appconfig.prod.json**

> - assets/
>
>   - appconfig.json
>   - **appconfig.prod.json**

It's not possible to copy different **assets** files based on environment: [angular/angular-cli#9634](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9634)

But angular-cli supports [Multiple Apps integration](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps).

You can copy the app object, modify **assets** configuration and add a name in **angular-cli.json**:

```json
"apps": [
    {
        ...
        "assets": [
            {
                "glob": "**/!(appconfig.prod.json)",
                "input": "./assets/",
                "output": "./assets/"
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    },
    {
        "name": "prod",
        ...
        "assets": [
            {
                "glob": "**/!(appconfig.*)",
                "input": "./assets/",
                "output": "./assets/"
            },
            {
                "glob": "appconfig.prod.json",
                "input": "./assets/",
                "output": "./assets/appconfig.json"
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
],
```

**Usage:**

```
ng build -prod -app=prod
```

Comment: interesting approach.

Comment: Did you use it?

Comment: No. I rewrote how Abp gets the file to include any environment setting too.